# How to refresh Quote from Quote Line entity using Client API?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am calling an Web API from Quote Line form through ajax call.

The API is updating Tax field in quote line entity. When i get success response form API, I need to refresh for getting the updated tax data from front end by using this.

> Xrm.Page.data.refresh(true).then(successCallBack, errorCallback);

But this updated tax is not being reflected in related sub-grid in Quote entity. If i refresh the browser then i am getting that but i don't want that.

How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Refresh not only your Record (Quote Line) but also Sub grid (Quote).

You need to use below code snippet in your successCallBackfunction.
I have shown for Contact subgrid but you can updated with your grid name.

```
function doSomething(executionContext) {
       var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext(); // get the form Context
       var gridContext = formContext.getControl("Contacts"); // get the grid context Name of gird which you wish to have context of

       // Perform operations on the subgrid
    gridContext.refresh();

    }
```

Comment: I can get the executionContext of quote line but how to get get the executionContext of quote?

Comment: you don't need execution context of Quote rather of quote line. I believe on your quote line entity you have sub grid for Quote?
just add debugger and see you will get gird context of your grid.

Comment: I didn't find any sub-grid for quote in quote line entity. Or am i missing something? Can you please help me how to get that?

Comment: @ProtapGhosh could you post screenshot from where exactly you are calling and where exactly you wish to update/refresh sub grid. From your question it looks that you have sub grid on from which needs to be refreshed

Comment: @ProtapGhosh did you managed to solve it? if yes what did you do?

Comment: Yes. I had to change the api. Previously i was updating the tax field from backend through the api. Now i am returning tax data from the api and updating it from quote line form which eventually updating tax column in the sub-grid of quote form.